# How to remove "mysterious" tooltips on iphone?

Tags: iphone, bug, accessibility

Suddenly, the following tool tips have appeared above every single item on an iPhone.
They appear above app icons, above each text message, etc

I *assume* its an accessibility feature but can't, for the life of me, find the setting that is causing it.

Googling yields no answer

Phone details:

OS: 15.3.1
Model: MX9R2X/A iPhone SE

This continues after restarting the phone

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked it down to an accessibility setting:

`Settings -> Accessibility -> Voice Control -> Overlay = "None"`